# Lyx: how to set the output label of my figures and table

Tags: tables, floats, lyx, labels

In 2011 I used `Lyx` to compile my PhD. I have to recompile it today, but I have an issue in style.

My table and figure label are  written in 2011 like:

```
FIGURE 1.1: my description

TABLE 1.1: my description
```

but it is now written like:

```
TABLE 1.1 - my descritpion
```

The "-" is too long for me, it completely change my page organization.

How can I come back to my original version with `Lyx`?

Comment: With which version of Lyx and TeX distribution did you compile 2011, with which versions today? Did you change the code? How?

Comment: It was certainly the standard instalation (tex included) of lyx. If i check the previous download of lyx it should be the version 1.6.8. Now, i use the current one (without code modification), version 2.3.3

Comment: @lelorrain7 are you sure you did not update your TeX distribution? That could also explain the difference. Do you still have LyX version 1.6.8 available so you can test with the updated TeX distribution? Are you able to share the original document in 1.6.x format? It could be a lyx2lyx bug that we need to fix but we won't be able to fix it without a document in 1.6.x format. If you can make a minimal example in 1.6.x format, please make a bug report on https://www.lyx.org/trac and choose component "lyx2lyx". If not, then consider sending your document privately to a lyx dev.

Answer (score 0):

Figures labeling changed and list "-" as well. Because my distribution is not the same (8 years later it looks normal) and because old installation of lyx I tried failed on windows 10, I manage my solution in using \small tex command where figure label were an issue. It works for le but it's not a real solution.

Many thanks for the time spending.